# How to remove horizontal scroll in Nicescroll.js?

Tags: horizontal-scrolling, nicescroll

I tried using `$("body").niceScroll({horizrailenabled:false});` and `body{overflow-x: hidden}`
but both didn't work. I have horizontal scroll on some resolutions like on `480px`, not on all.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the param to the plugin:

```
$("#boxscroll").niceScroll({horizrailenabled:false});
```

and then remove the native scroll from the element:

```
<div id="boxscroll" style="overflow-x:hidden;"></div>
```

It is well documented on the nicescroll repo here: https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/issues/114